# Calculating an infinite sum and finding a limit

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, summation

Is it possible to evaluate or find the solution to the following infinite sum with an inverse trigonometric function (arctan), and its limit?

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan \left(\frac{x}{1-(x-n)^2}\right)$

What methods could be used to solve it?

This question was asked on Quora, but it looks that there is not a definite or accurate answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean inverse trigonometric function, or is $\arctan$ meant to be $\textrm{artanh}$? Because if the latter, then you can express it as a logarithm which then turns the infinite sum into an infinite product that might have some nice telescoping properties.

Comment: @ConMan it's arctan.

Comment: Could you provide the link to the question in Quora ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici it was a random math question in the general feed page, it's the same question nothing added. It can be difficult to find it with the Quora search engine being inaccurate and the questions not ordered. Last I saw there are 2 answers, one using calculus approximation methods, the other using Mathematica numerical techniques. But the answers didn't agree.

Comment: I made an answer for the integral instead of the sum. Since it has been immediately downvoted, I deleted it. Do you want it ?

Comment: Yes if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem was $$f(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\int_{1}^\infty \arctan \left(\frac{x}{1-(x-n)^2}\right)\,dn$$ we have the antiderivative (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BArcTan%5Bx%2F%281+-+%28-n+%2B+x%29%5E2%29%5D%2Cn%5D)).

Even if not looking nice, its series expansion for large values of $x$ will be
$$f(x)=\pi \sqrt 2-\frac{1}{x^{\frac 12}}+\frac{\pi }{x\sqrt{2} }-\frac{1}{x^{\frac 32}}+\frac{\pi }{4x^2\sqrt{2} }-\frac {19}{15x^{\frac 52}}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

Comment: I am in the process of studying advanced calculus. Could you explain how you found the series expansion for f(x)? Did you maybe use the Euler Maclaurin formula?

Comment: @fsrong70. Not at all. Take the nasty formula; make $n=1$ (at $\infty$, it is $0$). Now, basic Taylor expansion.